# What is this offset in my sumASCII function?

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm trying to write a function that will sum the ASCII digits of every character in a string input. However, if I don't provide the +48 offset in my code, the function will return a value that's -48 off. What is this offset?

```
int sumASCII (string input) {
    int index = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int strLen = (int)input.length();

    while (index < strLen) {
        sum = (input[index] - '0') + sum + 48;
        index++;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Evidently, your array does not contain ASCII digits. Either that, or you expected the function to return 96 for the string "00", whereas the function was intended to return 0 for "00"

Comment: Please give example input, expected result and actual result. If the input is correct and you are trying to interpret each character as a decimal digit then should not need the offset. But it is unclear what it is exactly that you want. So please provide requested info.

Comment: It's not clear what the goal here is. What should the result be when the function is called with the text `"12"`? As written (and assuming the compiler uses ASCII), the result is `'1' + '2'`, which isn't a particularly useful value. Or should it return `'3'`, which is arguably meaningful, although there are many input strings for which the sum is greater than `'9'`.

Answer (score 1):

'0' has the ascii value of 48. So if we look at your code, and replace '0' with 48, you might notice the problem....

```cpp
sum = input[index] - 48 + sum + 48;
```

So you might as well replace that with:

```cpp
sum += input[index];
```